# sonarqube mixed obj-c swift project, how scan is done for code coverage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, sonarqube

According to the docs, both the swift and Obj-C sonar scanners want code coverage data and in different ways (build-wrapper vs xccov). But this got me thinking, code coverage is for an **entire** target/project in xcode, not just files for a particular *language*. So for a mixed Obj-C **and** swift project, does SonarQube want the same entire-project-xcode-generated coverage data twice (once per scanner)? If not, how does it relate code coverage for a particular language in a sonar project, or does it not care at all?

Only asking this because again, and much to my surprise, the docs for the 2 scanners list different code coverage instructions, leading the user to wonder if each scanner doesn't expect the data to be mixed together like it is with xcode and a mixed obj-c swift project (i.e. its the **same** data)

Answer (score 0):

Even i am facing same scanario. What we are currently doing is we setup build-wrapper utility as indicated at https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/cfamily/.
So, initially it worked fine for a month or so. Later, we start getting following error:

====================================================================================
02:36:25.658 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
02:36:25.658 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The "build-wrapper-dump.json" file was found but 0 C/C++/Objective-C files were analyzed. Please make sure that:
  * you are using the latest version of the build-wrapper and the SonarCFamily analyzer
  * you are correctly invoking the scanner with correct configuration  * your compiler is supported
  * you are wrapping your build correctly
  * you are wrapping a full/clean build
  * you are providing the path to the correct build-wrapper output directory

====================================================================================

So, we have decide to install a backelite plug-in / jar (that handles sonar coverage reports for a mix of Swift and Objective-C) to our sonar server (Enterprise edition) , but, it led to the following error:

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cLLI.png)

So, basically you can set uo build wrapper utility and try performing the sonar scan.  Make sure sonar-scanner is installed and you are passing relevant switches to the sonar-scanner command.

Comment: you can get help on the SonarSource community forum https://community.sonarsource.com/